# C - Sum of numbers

Tags: c, sum

Why won't my program work? It is supposed to add numbers from a formula 1-(1/2)+(1/3)...+(1/999)-(1/1000)=

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main () {
 int i, j;
 float  suma;
 suma = 0.f;
 for (i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    if (i%2==0) {
        suma=suma - 1/i;
    } else {
        suma=suma + 1/i;
    }
 }
 printf("%f", suma);

}
```

Comment: BTW: Suggest summing in the reverse order `for (i = 1000; i >= 1; i--)` to improve accuracy.

Answer (score 7):

Divide by zero !!

```
int main () {
 int i;
 float  suma;
 suma = 0.0f; 
 for (i=1; i<1000; i++) {  //fix loop, start from 1
    if (i%2==0) {
        suma=suma - 1.0f/i; // Use 1.0, (1/i will be evaluated as int)
    } else {
        suma=suma + 1.0f/i;
    }
 }
 printf("%f", suma);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try printing `1 / i` with `i` being an `int`. This will always returns 0, except when `i` is `1`. This happens because `1 / i` is evaluated as an [Euclidean division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) with the remainder being discarded.

The reason this is evaluated like this is because `1` and `i` are both integer.
You need to either the numerator or the denominator to be of floating point type.

One way is to cast `i` to a float, so your code would look like this: `suma = suma - 1 / (float)i`. The other way is to make `1` be of floating point type: `suma = suma - 1.0 / i` or `suma = suma - (float)1 / i`.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop started from 0.
so the first iteration returns divide by zero error.
second iteration will return 1/1=1 and will work good, but from third iteration it will return 0, because you are using int. Try starting the for loop from 1 and typecast i to float.

Answer (score 1):

You will get much higher accuracy if you apply some math first. Your series:

```
1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + ... + 1/999 - 1/1000
```

can be rewritten as:

```
(1 - 1/2) + (1/3 - 1/4) + ... + (1/999 - 1/1000)
```

or as:

```
1/(1*2) + 1/(3*4) + ... + 1/(999*1000)
```

Now, you can write a program to perform calculation. However, you should use `double` type to improve accuracy and cast integer to double to make sure that your series are added as double numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    int i;
    double sum = 0;
    for (i=1; i<1000; i+=2) {
        sum += 1/(i*(i+1.)); // 1. to force cast to double
    }
    printf("%g", sum);
}
```

Comment: It is nice that this answer shows how to improve the accuracy, but it does not state or explain the two fundamental bugs in the original code (an erroneous starting value for the loop that causes divide by zero and an integer division where floating-point is needed).

Comment: Tried this and @elhadi method, both as `double`.  13 ULP difference.  Suggest that you get even _better_ accuracy by summing in the reverse order 999 to 1, via either method.

Answer (score 0):

herein a simple program

```
float j = 1.0f;
float suma = 0.0f;
int i = 1;

for (i=1; i <= 1000; i++) {
   suma += j/i;
   j = j * (-1);
}
```

Comment: Curious: why not "j = -j"?  Suppose the compiler will optimize either way.